# Printing an array created from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, string, text-files

Trying to print an array with lines from a text file.

Text file:

```
Queen Greatest_Hits_I Rock 2011 UNI 17 58.19

Madonna Music Pop 2000 Mavericks_Records 10 44.40

Miles_Davies King_of_Blue Jazz 1959 Columbia_Records 6 45.44

Charles_Bradley Changes Soul 2016 Daptone_Records 11 40.44

David_Bowie Blackstar Rock 2016 ISO 7 41.13

Queen Queen_II

Prince Purple_Rain
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

    Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("C:\\CD.txt"));
    int a=0,i=0;
    while(read.hasNext()){
        a++;
        read.nextLine();
    }read.close();

    String [] l = new String [a];
    read= new Scanner(new File("C:\\CD.txt"));
    while(read.hasNext()){
        String n =read.nextLine();
        l[i]=n;
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l));
}
```

Code output:

```
[Queen Greatest_Hits_I Rock 2011 UNI 17 58.19, Madonna Music Pop 2000 Mavericks_Records 10 44.40, Miles_Davies King_of_Blue Jazz 1959 Columbia_Records 6 45.44, Charles_Bradley Changes Soul 2016 Daptone_Records 11 40.44, David_Bowie Blackstar Rock 2016 ISO 7 41.13, Queen Queen_II, Prince Purple_Rain]
```

The output I want:

```
Queen Greatest_Hits_I Rock 2011 UNI 17 58.19
Madonna Music Pop 2000 Mavericks_Records 10 44.40
Miles_Davies King_of_Blue Jazz 1959 Columbia_Records 6 45.44
Charles_Bradley Changes Soul 2016 Daptone_Records 11 40.44
David_Bowie Blackstar Rock 2016 ISO 7 41.13
Queen Queen_II
Prince Purple_Rain
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of adding each line to an array, just output the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l));` try this:

```
for (String line : l) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Or without loop:

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.join(l, "\n"));
```

Java 8:

```
Arrays.stream(l).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. The problem is that `Arrays.toString()` returns a String representation of an array in the format that you see.

If you don't need an array, just output the lines as you read them.

If you need to write the lines in an array (to check if its contents are correct(?)), and you need to output each array element in a new line, just change the way you print an array. Instead of using `Arrays.toString()` method, use something like:

```
public String toString(String[] array) {
    for (String line : array) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

An improvement to your algorithm would be to scan the file once, store it in an Arraylist and, if you still need an array, apply the toArray() method on this Arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 you could use the Stream API.

```
 Stream.of(l).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your simplified code with the desired output :

```
       public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException{

    Scanner read= new Scanner(new File("C:\\CD.txt"));
        while(read.hasNext()){

            System.out.println(read.nextLine());
        }
}
```

Also, if you want to store the file in some sort of collection, you can use ArrayList for it, and still get the desired output. Below is for reference:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException{

ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner read= new Scanner(new File("C:\\CD.txt"));
while(read.hasNext()){

    arr.add(read.nextLine());

}

for(String str : arr)
{
    System.out.println(str);
}}
```